# Where are Hasura roles stored?

Tags: postgresql, roles, hasura, hasura-jwt

I want to create authentication apis in Hasura. My user can have differrent roles when signing up. Thinking of maintaining an Enum table for the same. So that I can have a foreign key/type from it in the user table. However, I intend to create a postgress trigger on this enum table, such that everytime, new role is added, a new hasura role should also be created to allow for JWT authentication and authorization accordingly.
Where does hasura stores its Hasrua role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer 1 (direct answer)

Not sure this is something the app developer should edit.

All Hasura metadata (including roles/permissions) is in Postgres.

The schema is **"hdb_catalog"**. The table is **"hdb_metadata"**.

You can query this using:

```
SELECT * FROM "hdb_catalog"."hdb_metadata" WHERE id = 1;
```

It contains a large JSON document. It's better to look at it using PGAdmin.

### Answer 2 (dynamic roles)

It looks like you're trying to get dynamic roles in place.
There is a great Youtube video that explains how to model it:

https://youtu.be/-18zZO3DrLY?t=1370